# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in index.php YII

Tags: php, yii

I have to close access to my index.php main page, I modified siteController.php with following code:

```
public function accessRules() {
  return array(
    // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions *
    array('allow',
      'actions' => array('index','view'),
      'users' => array('admin'),
    ),
    // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions @
    array('allow',
      'actions' => array('create','update'),
      'users' => array('admin'),
    ),
    // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
    array('allow',
      'actions' => array('admin','delete'),
      'users' => array('admin'),
    ),
    // deny all users
    array('deny',
      'users' => array('*'),
    ),
  );
}
```

Because I have to give access only for admin. After this manipulations I saw that redirect is working, and url becomes *index.php/site/login*, but instead of *login/pass* form I got `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`. Hope you could understand me)

Comment: By the way, actionLogin is located in the siteController.php, maybe it could be a reason of redirecting

Comment: Maybe you need to add login to allowed actions?))

Comment: You have redirect loop, because you not logged in -> redirect to login -> login not in access rules `(deny',  // deny all users 'users'=>array('*'))` ->redirect to login page. Add your login action to access rules: `array('allow',    'actions'=>array('index','view','login'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),`

Comment: oh, stupid mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Please put light on what happened ?

Comment: I've forgot to say I am using `yii2`

Comment: post your config/main.php

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and the solution is to add the "error" action to the rules, allowing all users to access it.
I got into this because after doing an update it generated an error and the error action couldn't be accessed.

Answer (score 1):

Ihad same problem and the problem with `urlManager` in `config/main.php`.
My urlManager config was like that:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'baseUrl' => $baseUrl,
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    // Disable index.php
    'showScriptName' => false,
    // Disable r= routes
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'rules' => [
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\w+>' => '<controller>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',


    ]
]
```

and it must be

```
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>',
```

It relation with RegEx. Here is [doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#url-rules)

Answer (score 0):

Add `login` action to access rules:

```
['allow', 
 'actions'=>['index','view','login'],
 'users'=>['admin'], 
],
```

Comment: if you do like this, you couldn't open login page